# Is there a way to force implicit conversion in function template argument deduction?

Tags: c++, template-argument-deduction, function-templates

I have this `count_` function template that counts the occurrences of a value in a vector of that its type:

```
template <typename T>
std::size_t count_(std::vector<T> const& vt, T const& value)
{
    std::cout << "count_(vector<T>, T const&)\n";
    std::size_t n{};
    for(auto const& e : vt)
        if(e == value)
            ++n;
    return n;
}

template <>
std::size_t count_(std::vector<char const*> const& vcp, char const * const& value)
{
    std::cout << "count_(vector<char const*>, char const*const&)\n";

    std::size_t n{};
    for(auto const& e : vcp)
        if( !strcmp(e, value))
            ++n;
    return n;
}



int main()
{

    std::vector<std::string> vs{"function", "C++", "template", "C++", "specialization", "partial", "C++", "full"};
    std::cout << count_(vs, std::string("C++")) << '\n';

    std::vector<double> vd{3.14, 5.2, 7.7, 3.14, 56.87, 3.14, 6.8798, 12.545};
    std::cout << count_(vd, 3.14) << '\n';

    std::cout << count_(std::vector{7, 24, 16, 7, 81, 7, 5, 7, 23, 10, 7, 15, 8}, 7) << '\n';

    std::vector<char const*> vcp{"function", "C++", "template", "C++", "specialization", "partial", "C++", "full"};
    std::cout << count_(vcp, static_cast<char const*>("C++")) << '\n';


    std::cout << "\ndone!\n";
}
```

- The program works just fine however I always need to explicitly cast or pass the second argument to the type of the element type of the `vector` that is passed as the first argument.
- I know this occurs due to the limited number or allowed implicit conversion in template Argument Deduction. And if `count_` is an ordinary non-template function then it works OK without casting a literal string to a constant pointer to char.

So is there a better way to avoid such casts `std::string("C++")`, `static_cast<char const*>("C++")`...?

I guess there is something like "meta-programming" if so could you elaborate an example please?

Comment: Your specialization appears to be quite broken and will only count identical pointer values. The only reason it appears to work is because of your compiler's string literal optimizations, but this can change at any time, of course. Perhaps you want to try to fix this, first?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: How?

Comment: When do you believe will `if (e == value)` be true, where both `e` and `value` are `const char *`? This is a multiple choice pop quiz: 1) when the pointer values are identical, 2) when the pointers point to the same string literal, even if they are different pointers.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: Ah! right! Do I use `strcmp`?

Comment: Well, how do you normally check if two `const char *`s point to the same literal string? You fix it exactly the same way, here.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: Edited

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Command the template argument to be deduced from the vector, but not from the value

```
template<typename T> //                                             v      only required change       v
typename std::vector<T>::size_type count_(std::vector<T> const &vt, typename std::vector<T>::value_type const &value) {
    std::cout << "count_(vector<T> const&, T const&)\n";
    typename std::vector<T>::size_type n = 0;
    for(auto const &e : vt) if(e == value) n++;
    return n;
}
```

Template parameter deduction basically cannot "see" through type aliases, especially not ones that are members of an as-yet unknown specialization. The second argument to `count_` no longer participates in deducing `T`. Rather, the `vector` always decides `T`, and then the second argument is implicitly converted to its type. Your specialization remains a specialization. Actually, it doesn't change.

```
// just cosmetic changes
template<>
std::vector<char const*>::size_type count_(std::vector<char const*> const &vcp, char const *const &value) {
    std::cout << "count_(vector<char const*> const&, char const *const&)\n";
    std::vector<char const*>::size_type n = 0;
    for(auto const &e : vcp) if(!std::strcmp(e, value)) n++;
    return n;
}
```

[Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qhkAUgBMAISnTSAZ0ztkBPHUqZa6AMKpWAVwC2tENwCspLegAyeWpgByxgEaZiIAMyTSAB1QKhOq0eoYmZpb%2BgWp0dg7ORm4e3orKmKrBDATMxAShxqYWqSoxtFk5BHFOru5ePgrZufnhRQ0VVQlJdQCUiqgGxMgcAORSnvbIhlgA1OKeOsgNxPbAc9jiAAwAgmMTU5iz8%2BpLmMxGa5s7kuO0kwYzczoAbulExBfblwSYRr7C348CABPXxaM4HAAqHy2wNBtHB0wa6BAIBeqhIjyhnmwKMCAC9MAB9WEHNAGeiEiBIlFot6YtbTNC0BqzSQANieBFI0xJ8KMB2pqNeGPmWJxqLYBiJJMZdBZUg5ksw3VmAHZZNtplrEQRkSh%2BgRDjpHqzJGSKRBaSKdGLZcyCAruRC7Q0Fd1xOYdLQpJI5hqttqeSCwfydXqre9RWtcXgCcTg9NaIcACLTDZ%2By6BmjECDMAxEF2GhUHEDTTkqvBUCAHObJ2tlpUq70yOQZzXa4iYAgDJPezz%2B8Squvbb6/f6YR7QwURx7IBA5QsAKmjIHx0oT5oIlOnwsjC3nxCXDKZ8vZT2Qvm5c4XJ8Ni9vrMVhmVav9gcFZKL8xNPs3lJn8zXoet7LtihaOoyB6FtM95yg67Lup6za%2Bv2mbaju6J7kBR7YjGcYykm9bpqh7Zatmub5qg0HFtMpbnr4FZVmAYCCksyC/NW3JPI2Tati2JEBh2XY9ombY7EOlz2IaRjMPYEAqoOb7obqNK7o8rEEMsogMk8CiKT6VDkhkdA%2BtyPrGi2lk%2BKao5/MwAKSNZ5l8bIjlmY5CigsgeBsLG9nBKZpq%2BBUPmsIFzmWa5TmOYZrBhY5g51gJ74qfq%2BZGiaf6Wgo7mSBZrlRQp37zNMYCjEhZViWhWoYXS8zoP0LjsDp6CKZ4AB0PDcuY7XWaq7WqtyHVddM5hsu1AAcg3TMNvDTONU0AJwTdynCSO15gWIlYkpXqn4ZSVWVPOgQ2ddwRXGiVlUVaMAmXLsVDTIShIXoYnlvYc6yeKmkgbJwqobJ4NjVdMAD0oPTNmPIIAKqURjyPx2d80w5MAxhaIaWDoAYxneqRYYovtk6Hf0Fq1Ri6rTZIc2cGy3LTRNnD091zPTNcq0bKznCWNME2JfTF0mtdXqVXd1zWJW934%2BTWFQSBOkXvpMVGaU4WOflfHRZItnjmreUuXrnnpKFfmq25QUhWwesa1ZuWxfFvoSclyl7QaB06LK5JbpaF65TbhXu6V5Ui7dA5DsMvSsCAwzmMMpCmMMGxx6g0f%2B4i/SDDW1ycHHBDR0n3S9AA1iAbKcJ1njc79i3cBs3ATdwNdCNH3BxwnSekCnwxxwoICc3nicR6QcCwEgmAAB7pJRZAULmxDAAoAAKIjKAwCCoAA7gnOekGgvx4P8wTLw4rBr5v7dx3vvgH7UkwiMAnCcBsnNXzfxAAPL5mfW/53HE/pFseevdu5WEnsgLI%2BAE5xxoPQJgbAOBdQEEzYQogUAuSEHgFwvdIC9FQL4UowCAC0SJawSEio/aYhCADqbBWA9wzkMQQSJ7DH1XuvH%2Bwwd4b2IMwXw0cc6R2jrHeOv9O7R3HhNNkhC2TcEZCg4A0xH7tQ2Mo6Y2AwHT2mBAXAhASCskriqf2udf6F1ICXTwE1JpsgbqqRaGxzCLXMNzDYdMo7DFbqQIwXBn4iMHmIkBvd%2B4mMEcMSQbdRFd2MYPUxLxiCBA0NwIAA)

Note: in this case we're "lucky" that `std::vector<T>::value_type` is a conveniently available alias for `T`. In general, you can use `std::type_identity_t<T>` as a template deduction blocker, but that's only available in C++20. (Of course, you can implement it yourself—it's only two lines!)

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution is to use a forwarding reference:

```
template <typename T, typename Value>
std::size_t count_(std::vector<T> const& vt, Value &&value)
{
    std::cout << "count_(vector<T>, T const&)\n";
    std::size_t n{};
    for(auto const& e : vt)
        if(e == value)
            ++n;
    return n;
}
```

And with this, `count_(vs, "C++")` will compile.

Note that the specialization will need to be adjusted, accordingly:

```
template <typename Value>
std::size_t count_(std::vector<char const*> const& vcp, Value && value)

// ...
```

You'll need to keep in mind that this template will now participate in overload resolution in more situations than before (due to the forwarding reference). If that's undesirable (if there are other overloads of `count_`) some additional work will be needed to have this template get excluded from overload resolution, when it won't compile.

Comment: So the second version is an overload and not a specialization right?

Comment: No, it's still a specialization. It specializes the original template with the first parameter specialized as `const char *`, just as before.

Comment: But a specialization doesn't participate in function matching? I've learned this from C++ primer?

Comment: But the original template still does. The "this template" in the final paragraph refers to the entire template, not just the specialization.

Comment: So it is overloaded not specialized?

Comment: No, the template has a specialization. But the template ***itself*** will participate in overload resolution in more situations where it otherwise wouldn't, and that could cause problems.

Comment: The two functions in this answer are separate templates overloading the same function name. There are no specializations in this answer. You can't partially specialize function templates.

Comment: @HTNW: This is what I've learned too. A function template can on;y be fully-specialized but not "partially" like class templates. on the other hand the latter(class-template) cannot be overloaded because they are classes not functions. And because the function template allows only full-specialization then their specialization's template parameter list must be a pair of empty angle brackets. Right?

Comment: Fair enough; the point I was making is that the forwarding reference makes the template(s) participate in overload resolution in more cases when they otherwise wouldn't; which can produce unwanted results. In which case some of the usual tricks will need to be employed to keep the template off the radar screen.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: Thanks a lot for your effort and help.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I like this solution because it doesn't require conversions for `value` (which allows `std::string` to compare with `const char*`); however I think forwarding is overkill for this scenario. `value` is only used in equality operations; which should always be an immutable operation -- so `const Value&` should be sufficient and have less cognitive overhead.