# How to do implicit conversion by passing as a parameter in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11

```
template <typename T>
class Prop {
public:
    Prop(const std::function<T()> &getter) : getter(getter) {}
    Prop(const T &value) : getter([=]() { return value; }) {}
    Prop(const char *value) : getter([=]() { return std::string(value); }) {}

    T operator()() const {
        return getter();
    }

private:
    const std::function<T()> getter;
};
```

When passed as a parameter to a non-template function, it does implicit conversion, but not when passed as a parameter to a template function.

```
void foo(const Prop<int> &prop) {}

template <typename T>
void bar(const Prop<T> &prop) {}

int main() {
    foo(0);
    bar(0); // no instance of function template "bar" matches the argument listC/C++(304)
}
```

Why is this happening, and how do I make it work with parameters in template functions?

Comment: There's no such thing as an implicit cast. A cast is something you write in your source code to tell the compiler to do a conversion; it's always explicit. The term you're looking for is "implicit conversion".

Comment: I added another bar template to call the first bar template: `template <typename T> void bar(T const& value) { bar(Prop{value}); }`

Comment: You can't have implicit conversion when deducing template parameter. Standard do not allow this, since whole hell would break loose if it would be possible. Number of possible ambiguities whould be astronomical and it would be nearly impossible to reason about code.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll have to find another way.

Comment: You could go: `bar<int>(0)`. As now you have an explicit version of the function. It can then understand and convert your `int` to a `Prop<int>` as normal.

Comment: As to why this doesn't work: for all the compiler knows, there's a `Prop<SomeClass>` specialization somewhere that also has a constructor from `int`; nothing says that `Prop<int>` is the only possibility. The compiler can't be expected to try `Prop<T>` for every possible type `T` (an infinite set) in the hopes of finding exactly one constructible from `int`.

Comment: See [Because template argument deduction is not that smart](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53227822/12002570) in the dupe [Why does the implicit type conversion not work in template deduction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53227713/why-does-the-implicit-type-conversion-not-work-in-template-deduction) and also [Is there a way to force implicit conversion in function template argument deduction?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65525535/12002570)